# Can bluetooth receive data for my app without it being open

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm exploring the BLE documentation in preparation for a project that I'll be working on very shortly.  I need to determine the scope and the power of bluetooth in terms of how it can interact with my app.

Feel free to point me toward the documentation that I have missed but I can't seem to determine if there is a way to have my application receiving the data from the bluetooth device prior to launching it.

Lets say I have an app that is designed to count my steps through out the day.  It would be rather tedious to open it every single morning just to initiate the step counting.

Does BLE have the functionality to be listening to the bluetooth device at all times?  Can I just send the steps to my app at regular intervals and let the app handle all of the data management for me to view when I open it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible. Apple provided us to run specific app's in background. Example Apps: news reading, audio playing, bluetooth dependent etc., To do this we need to enable background capabilities in Xcode as shown in below image.

[image]

For detailed explanation check below link.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html